# Как загрузить файл на одну страницу?

Tags: html, css, menu, href

Дико извиняюсь, я в этом новичок...
В общем, у меня есть сайт бар, в нем есть кнопки, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на допустим кнопку 'Города' В основной части сайта появились фото, или же какая-то статья о городах, НО! сайт бар или же меню, не менялись и оставались[image: введите сюда описание изображения] на том же месте?

Вот на фото у меня кнопка - 'Города' Я хочу что бы когда нажимала на неё, в это же окно загружался еще один файл с темой города. Но эта кнопка, оставалась на месте...
Извиняюсь за такие долгие написания, я и вправду в этом новичок и правильно высказаться не могу, кот знает как это делаеться, буду ооочень благодарна.

Comment: поиском не пробовали пользоваться? забили "загрузка контента на страницу без перезагрузки" , нашли нужное, попробовали, не получилось - скинули сюда. Вообще - это ajax, ну или если совсем сложно - смотрите в сторону фреймов.

Answer (score 1):

Про загрузку данных с сервера Вам уже ответ дали. А если все данные у Вас на клиенте, и Вам надо просто по клику на тот или иной пункт меню отображать разный контент, то можно использовать вкладки (tabs):

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}
label:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.strany,
.goroda,
.ulitsy {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
}
#strany:checked ~ .strany,
#goroda:checked ~ .goroda,
#ulitsy:checked ~ .ulitsy {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="strany" /><label for="strany">СТРАНЫ</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="goroda" /><label for="goroda">ГОРОДА</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="ulitsy" /><label for="ulitsy">УЛИЦЫ</label>

<div class="strany">
Здесь статья про страны
</div>

<div class="goroda">
Тут картинка с городами
</div>

<div class="ulitsy">
А в этом блоке что-то про улицы
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно грузить данные с сервера, то воспользуйтесь `ajax`

```js
let rout = [{Name: "Главная", View: "main"}, {Name: "Города", View: "city"}];
$("nav button").click(function(){
  rout.forEach(el => {
    if (el.Name == $(this).text()){
      $("#"+el.View).css("display","block");
    }
    else
      $("#"+el.View).css("display","none");
  });
});
```

```css
nav ul li{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><button>Главная</button></li>
  <li><button>Города</button></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<section id="main">
<h1>Приветствую на моем сайте</h1>
</section>
<section id="city" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li>Москва</li>
<li>Киев</li>
<li>Одесса</li>
</ul>
</section>
```